# Cambiar el color de salida en un JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Quiero que al momento de mandar cualquiera de los mensajes, ya sea debil, invalido, etc.., este mensaje lo pueda cambiar de color.

```
jQuery(function($){
        $(".check-seguridad").strength({
            templates: {
                toggle: '<span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open {toggleClass}"></span></span>';   
            },
            scoreLables: {
                    empty: 'Vacío',
                    invalid: 'Invalido',
                    weak: 'Débil',
                    good: 'Bueno',
                    strong: 'Fuerte'
            }, 
            scoreClasses: {
                    empty: '',
                    invalid: 'label-danger',
                    weak: 'label-warning',
                    good: 'label-info',
                    strong: 'label-success'
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: No tengo idea que hace el JS que publicaste. Pero veo que estás asignando a cada tipo de mensaje una clase ("label-danger", "label-warning", etc). Con lo cual, lo que deberías hacer es desde `CSS` asignar un color a cada clase. Ejemplo: `.label-info { color: #076cf9; }`

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso es justo lo que necesitaba.